# Пункты меню не отображаются в строке меню Apple.

Tags: mac, java, swing

У меня есть приложение на Java с главным меню. Но при запуске на Маке эти пункты меню не отображаются в главной строке меню Apple вверху экрана, а располагаются в окне приложения стандартно, т.е. выглядит как в Windows. В чем может быть проблема? Меню создаю стандартным способом:

```
JMenuBar mainMenu = new JMenuBar();
mainMenu.add(new JMenu("Menu 1"));
...
frame.setJMenuBar(mainMenu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то надо либо использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку, которая использует нативные контролы (такая, как SWT), либо использовать аээпловское апи для этого меню (как делает, например, нетбинс)

Прочтите также вот это: [Bringing your Java Application to Mac OS X](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac/). В этой статье есть речь и про меню.

PS: я всё-таки не совсем прав. Однако, судя по документу, достаточно пропихнуть аргументы при запуске:

> > -Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true -Xdock:name="window name on dock panel"

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что Swing не работает из коробки на Mac OS? Это же бардак какой-то.

Comment: Отлично работает! Осталось только разобраться как вставить стандартную кнопку меню Help, в которой есть встроенный Search от Apple - поиск пункта меню по названию.